# Веб-ориентированные приложения против мобильных приложений

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2, phpstorm, мобильные-приложения

Суть этого вопроса заключается в том, чтобы определиться, какое приложение будет лучшим: веб-ориентированное или мобильное приложение. Допустим если есть сайт ведения домашней бухгалтерии, то каким он должен быть? Веб-ориентированным или все-таки лучше мобильным? Сам сайт пишется в среде PhpStorm на фреймворке Yii2 и использует архитектурный шаблон MVC. Основное преимущество веб-ориентированных приложений, что они кроссбраузерные и могут прекрасно работать в любом браузере любого устройства. Веб-ориентированное приложение можно со временем интегрировать в мобильное приложение. Как Вы считаете, стоит ли делать мобильную версию сайта домашней бухгалтерии? Какие недостатки мобильных приложений по сравнению с веб-ориентированными? Всегда стоит изменять инструментарий и среды разработки для создания мобильного приложения, если есть готовое веб-ориентированное? И как быстро можно превратить приложение, написанное на Yii2, в мобильное? Я в процессе изучения недостатков мобильных приложений, поэтому мне очень важно ваше мнение, поскольку я больше придерживаюсь позиции, что веб-ориентированные все таки будут лучше, но мне важно услышать Ваше мнение.

Comment: Не путайте приложения и сайты, приложения работают на телефоне, а сайты в браузере, вот вам и ответ, если сделать удобное и функциональное приложение, то это гораздо удобнее и быстрее, чем пользоваться браузером и ждать загрузок вашего сайта. даже если вы его и Адаптируете под мобильные устройства, то все равно это будет в проигрыше по сравнению с приложением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делай на Yii2 rest api, а там уж все равно какой клиент будет взаимодействовать с данными. С таким подходом можно сделать браузерное приложение на vue (angular, react) или хоть на том же jQuery (прости господи). Также ничего не помешает сделать мобильное приложение, которое будет работать с данными через все тот же апи. А когда дела пойдут в гору, тогда можно даже десктопное приложение для винды сделать (мало ли у кого нет мобильника, а браузер жутко тормозит или нельзя им пользоваться на работе).
А если делать веб-версию, то сейчас уже надо ориентироваться на мобилки в первую очередь, а потом уже на мониторы ПК. Mobile first, так сказать.